# Create textbox (label) with click on link Javascript

Tags: javascript, hyperlink, label, appian

I have one label that upload files, and below the label I have link "Upload more" that when I click on it, it have to create me another label same like the previous one. I'm doing this in Appian.

```
<a href="javascript:callShowHideLabel1("label2")">Upload More</a>
```

where label2 is my next label, and this goes to Instructions (if someone is familiar with Appian)

Here is my function:

```
function ShowHideLabel1(label){
    var l = FormAPI.getValue(label).id;
    window.FormAPI.show(label);
    return true;
}
```

**Where do I go wrong?**

Answer (score 0):

Try

```
<a href="javascript:callShowHideLabel1('label2')">Upload More</a>
```

Using single quotation marks in the javascript code, you avoid conflicts with the quotes from your html code.

But please keep in mind that this is bad practise. You should bind a click event to that link firing the javascript code and set your `href` to a simple `#`.